# how should i move up or down the custom plot symbol drawing using Core-plot in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I used to charts using core-plot framework, my requirement is draw vertical line as a plot symbol in scatter chart, i need to move up or down according the value, how should i do it?
please help me out?

Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement one of the following methods in your datasource:

```
-(NSArray *)symbolsForScatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
-(CPPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

You can create as many different plot symbols as you need. Simply return the correct one for each point.

Eric